# Is there any WinAPI function to modify the desktop icon size?

Tags: winapi

Maybe I did not do a good search, but cannot find any WinAPI function to modify the desktop icons size. If there is not, can you suggest a way to achieve that?

Comment: Try Shell API? ..

Comment: It would be in the shell API if anywhere, or perhaps as a group policy setting. But this is considered a user setting so your program surely should not be changing it, unless it's only on machines you control.

Answer (score 7):

Get the [`IFolderView2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775541(v=vs.85).aspx) interface of the desktop and call its [`SetViewModeAndIconSize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775573(v=vs.85).aspx) method to change the icon size.

The hard thing is how to get the `IFolderView2` interface for the desktop. Fortunately, Raymond Chen comes to the rescue. He has an article about [manipulating the positions of desktop icons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933/) from which we only need the code of his `FindDesktopFolderView()` function.

I have adapted his code with added error handling. Although this question is tagged "C" I'm using C++ to answer it because C++ is more practical for COM programming.

First the required includes and some helper functions.

```
#include <ShlObj.h>     // Shell API
#include <atlcomcli.h>  // CComPtr & Co.
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <system_error>

// Throw a std::system_error if the HRESULT indicates failure.
template< typename T >
void ThrowIfFailed( HRESULT hr, T&& msg )
{
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        throw std::system_error{ hr, std::system_category(), std::forward<T>( msg ) };
}

// RAII wrapper to initialize/uninitialize COM
struct CComInit
{
    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize( nullptr );
    CComInit() { ThrowIfFailed( hr, "CoInitialize failed" ); }
    ~CComInit() { ::CoUninitialize(); }
};
```

Now down to the nitty-gritty, **`FindDesktopFolderView()`**:

```
// Query an interface from the desktop shell view.
void FindDesktopFolderView( REFIID riid, void **ppv, std::string const& interfaceName )
{
    CComPtr<IShellWindows> spShellWindows;
    ThrowIfFailed( 
        spShellWindows.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_ShellWindows ),
        "Failed to create IShellWindows instance" );

    CComVariant vtLoc( CSIDL_DESKTOP );
    CComVariant vtEmpty;
    long lhwnd;
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spdisp;
    ThrowIfFailed( 
        spShellWindows->FindWindowSW(
            &vtLoc, &vtEmpty, SWC_DESKTOP, &lhwnd, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH, &spdisp ),
        "Failed to find desktop window" );

    CComQIPtr<IServiceProvider> spProv( spdisp );
    if( ! spProv )
        ThrowIfFailed( E_NOINTERFACE, "Failed to get IServiceProvider interface for desktop" );

    CComPtr<IShellBrowser> spBrowser;
    ThrowIfFailed( 
        spProv->QueryService( SID_STopLevelBrowser, IID_PPV_ARGS( &spBrowser ) ),
        "Failed to get IShellBrowser for desktop" );

    CComPtr<IShellView> spView;
    ThrowIfFailed( 
        spBrowser->QueryActiveShellView( &spView ),
        "Failed to query IShellView for desktop" );

    ThrowIfFailed( 
        spView->QueryInterface( riid, ppv ),
        "Could not query desktop IShellView for interface " + interfaceName );
}
```

**Usage Example:**

The following example sets the desktop icon size to 16, which is even smaller than what you can achieve through the context menu of the desktop.

You can also have some fun and set the `viewMode` to something else, say `FVM_DETAILS` which would switch the desktop into details view. That's not even possible through the regular user interface.

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        CComInit coInit;

        CComPtr<IFolderView2> spView;
        FindDesktopFolderView( IID_PPV_ARGS( &spView ), "IFolderView2" );

        FOLDERVIEWMODE viewMode = FVM_AUTO;
        int iconSize = 0;
        ThrowIfFailed( 
            spView->GetViewModeAndIconSize( &viewMode, &iconSize ),
            "GetViewModeAndIconSize failed" );
        std::cout << "Current view mode: " << viewMode << ", icon size: " << iconSize << '\n';

        ThrowIfFailed( 
            spView->SetViewModeAndIconSize( viewMode, 16 ),
            "SetViewModeAndIconSize failed" );

        return 0;
    }
    catch( std::system_error const& e )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << e.what() << ", error code: " << e.code() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I'm afraid you need C++ to do this."* - Why? You are using COM interfaces. COM interfaces can be used from C just as well. C++ makes it a bit easier and a bit more compact. A few notes here: `1` Catch by const reference. `2` The expression in the `if`-statement in the `CComInit` d'tor always evaluates to `true`. It can be removed.

Comment: @IInspectable Fixed that.